# How to click a link under span class in cypress

Tags: xpath, cypress

How to achieve click link in the below scenario. I want to find  "setup1" and click

```
<div class = "abc div " </div>
<span class = "abc expand"> setup1 </span>
```

Comment: Can you post the entire html and also post the code that you tried ?

Answer (score 1):

Simple CSS syntax and [cy.conains()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/contains#Selector) should suffice:

```
cy.contains ('span[class="abc expand"]', 'setup1').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you use 2 tags for this post, **xpath** and **cypress**, I assume that you want to use XPath.

Let us presume that you have "abc expand" `span` into "abc div" `div` (an empty div doesn't make much sense). So, using **cypress-xpath** the solution would be:

```js
cy.xpath('//div[@class="abc div"]/span').click();
```

Note that in order to use XPath, you must install it using the command: `npm install -D cypress-xpath` and then include in your project `cypress/support/index.js` this line
`require('cypress-xpath')`.

You can find more details about installation here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-xpath